# How can I adjust the position of a <div> depending upon the size of the <div> above on it?

Tags: html, css, position, divider

Let's assume that I have 2 `<div>` at the top and 1 long `<div>` below the 2 `<div>`

**Desired Output!**

```
|-----------|    |----------|
|           |    |          |
|   Div1    |    |          |
|           |    |    Div2  |
|           |    |          |
|-----------|    |          |
                 |----------|

|----------------------------|
|                            |
|          DIV 3             |
|----------------------------|
```

*height* and *width* of **Div 1** and **Div 2**, will depend on its inner content. So it may become longer and larger.

My question is, how can **DIV 3**, adjust its proportions from the `<div>`s above? In above case, **DIV 2** becomes longer and it causes DIV 3, to adjust down.

In my case, **DIV 3** blocks **DIV 2**.

```
    |-----------|    |----------|
    |           |    |          |
    |   Div1    |    |          |
    |           |    |    Div2  |
    |           |    |          |
    |-----------|    |          |
|-----------------------------------|                     
|                                   |
|               DIV 3               |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Notice at the illustration above, **div 3** blocks the oversize **div 2**.

This is my *Code* for this error:

```
<div id = 'divforimg'>
                        <img width="300px" height="300px" id = 'appimage'>
                        </div>

                        <div class = "divforinfo" id = "divinfo">
                            <i><p id = "appdesc"></p></i>
                            <strong>Price: </strong><label id = "appprice"></label><br>
                            <strong>Brand: </strong><label id = "appbrand"></label><br>
                            <strong>Color: </strong><label id = "appcolor"></label><br>
                            <strong>Model: </strong><label id = "appmodel"></label><br>
                            <strong>Available Quantity: </strong><label id = "appqty"></label><br>
                            <strong>Date Posted: </strong><label id = "appposted"></label><br>
                            <center><button class = "btn btn-primary" onclick = "hideDiv(2)">Edit Contents</button></center>
                        </div> 

<div id = "imagediv">
                        XX
                        </div>
```

And THE **CSS**:

```
#imagediv{
    height: 100px;
    width: 2000px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -20%;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#divforimg{ 
    float: left;
}

.divforinfo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

Please help me into this.

Comment: You should note that the `center` tag has been deprecated and should no longer be user. Also, a demo of the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use float or inline-block your first & second div & give it a width.

**DEMO**

```css
.first-div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
.second-div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}
.third-div {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
    <p>First div</p>
</div>
<div class="second-div">
    <p>Second div</p>
</div>
<div class="third-div">
    <p>Third div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
#imagediv{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#divforimg{ 
    float: left;
}

.divforinfo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

This makes the bottom div relative to the bottom of your screen, depending on your largest div.